# Problema de actualización en Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, div

Tengo un problema con este código lo que quiero hacer es que se actualice sin que parpadee el

Código Html:

`<div id="mostrar_mensaje" class="mostrar_mensaje"></div>`

Código js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var out, isScrolledToBottom;

    out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje"); // outer container of messages


    // initial load of chat                     ////**Chat post id
    $('#mostrar_mensaje').load("load_chat.php", function() {
      out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje"); // re-reference after a jQuery .load() as it removes the original dom element and add a new one
      scrollToBottom(true);
    });


    // check for chatter every second
    setInterval(function() {

        isScrolledToBottom = checkIfScrolledBottom();

        $('#mostrar_mensaje').load("load_chat.php", function() {
          out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje"); // re-reference after a jQuery .load() as it removes the original dom element and add a new one
          scrollToBottom(isScrolledToBottom);
        });

    }, 1000);

    function checkIfScrolledBottom() {
        // allow for 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
        return out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
    }

    function scrollToBottom(scrollDown) {
        if (scrollDown)
        out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
    }
    //setTimeout(function() { $("#chat-feed").scrollTop($("#chat-feed")[0].scrollHeight);}, 1200);
});
```

Código Css:

```
.mostrar_mensaje {
    height: 440px;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 96%;
    /* border-radius: 5px; */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php
        require("conectarbd.php");
        include ("app/data.php");

    ////**This file is for languages    
    if (@$_COOKIE["muser"]!='') {   
        require ("languages/".userdata('language',false).".php");
    } else {
        require ("languages/".$Language.".php");
    }




    $id = $_GET['v']; 
////** This is to know if the room exists   
        $DataPaste = mysql_query("SELECT * from paste WHERE pasteID=$id ");
    if (mysql_num_rows($DataPaste) == 0)
    {
                echo '<br><br><br><center><img src="'.$sitio_url.'img/500.png"></img><br>
                '.$Languages_136.'!</center>';

    }else{ 

            $data_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * from chat WHERE post=$id ");
            if (mysql_num_rows($data_chat) == 0)
            {
                        echo '<br><br><br><center><img src="'.$sitio_url.'img/no_messages.png"></img><br>
                        '.$Languages_12.'!</center>';
            }else{  

                while($res=mysql_fetch_array($data_chat)){
                        $ads=$res["ads"];
                        $pads=$res["pads"];
                        $embed=$res["link"];
                        $tipo=$res["tipo"];

/////Mensaje
                            $come[0]='';
                            $come[1]=''.$Ads_Two.'';
// // // // // // // // // // // // // // Content type------------------------->
// // // // // // chat

                             $type[0]='<div id="chat" class="message__chat">
                                                <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                            <div id="chat" class="wall_chat_body">
                                                <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam><br>'.parseString(nl2br(bb_parse(Hashtag(''.$res["mensaje"].'')))).'</p>
                                            </div>
                                       </div>'.$come[$ads].'';
// // // // // // imagen        
                            $type[1]='<div id="chat">
                                    <div class="message__img">
                                            <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                        <div class="wall_chat_body_image">
                                            <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="message__chat m--user">
                                            <div class="message__text t--user">
                                                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-media" data-id="'.$res["id"].'" id="getMedia">
                                                <img class="playgif" data-swap="Thumbnails?img='.upload_image($res["id"]).'&data='.$res["post"].'" src="Thumbnails?img='.upload_image($res["id"]).'&thumbs=1&data='.$res["post"].'" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>';
// // // // // // audio     
                            $type[2]='<div id="chat"><div class="message__img">
                                                    <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                                <div class="wall_chat_body_image">
                                                    <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam></p>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                    <div class="message__chat m--user">
                                        <p class="message__text t--user">
                                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-media" data-id="'.$res["id"].'" id="getMedia">
                                        <img src="img/tool.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
                                        </a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>';    



////** Here are the chat messages   
                    echo $type[$tipo];
////** This is the function for external links                  
                    echo ''.External_links($res["link"]).''; 

                }
            }
    }       
?>
```

Comment: Supongo que tu div es "#mostrar_mensaje", correcto? Y otra cosa, con "parpadear" te refieres a que aparezca y desaparezca en un periodo muy corto de tiempo, correcto?

Comment: id="mostrar_mensaje" así es aparezca y desaparezca porque pasa eso ?

Comment: Me imagino que es porque esa parte del html se vuelve a renderizar cuando actualizas todo. Quizas podrias probar con alguna animación de Jquery como .fadeIn(), .fadeOut() o .fadeToogle().

Comment: no tienes un ejemplo es para un chat por eso no quiero que pase eso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he creado el chat considerando tu codigo y la funcion `append` de `jquery` para evitar el parpadeo.
Considera:
1. El php `load_chat.php` la primera vez debe retornar todos los mensajes del chat.
2. El php `load_chat.php` las siguientes veces debe retornar solo los mensajes nuevos, para que append agregue al chat solo esos.

**Codigo front** (html, css, js):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .mostrar_mensaje {
        height: 440px;
        padding: 12px;
        width: 96%;
        /* border-radius: 5px; */
        overflow-x: hidden;
        border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mostrar_mensaje" id="mostrar_mensaje"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var out, isScrolledToBottom;
    out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje"); // outer container of messages

    // initial load of chat                     ////**Chat post id
    cargaMensajeChat(1,llenaMensajePrimeraVez);

    // check for chatter every second
    setInterval(function() {

        isScrolledToBottom = checkIfScrolledBottom();
        cargaMensajeChat(0,llenaMensajeSiguientesVeces);

    }, 1000);

    function checkIfScrolledBottom() {
        // allow for 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
        return out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
    }

    function scrollToBottom(scrollDown) {
        if (scrollDown)
        out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
    }

    //funcion carga mensajes del servidor por ajax
    function cargaMensajeChat(vFlagPrimeraVez,callback){
        var vidchat=obtenerUltimoIdChat();
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "load_chat.php",
            data: {
                flagPrimeraVez : vFlagPrimeraVez,
                idchat : vidchat
            },
            success: function(data){
                callback(data);             
            }
        })
    }
    //funcion llena div primera vez
    function llenaMensajePrimeraVez(contenido){
        $('#mostrar_mensaje').html(contenido);
    }
    //funcion llena agrega solo nuevos mensajes (append)
    function llenaMensajeSiguientesVeces(contenido){
        if($.trim(contenido)!=''){
            $('#mostrar_mensaje').append(contenido);
            out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje");
            scrollToBottom(isScrolledToBottom);
        }
    }
    //recorre los div del chat, todos tienen atributo id="chat", coge el ultimo que es quien tiene el mayor id
    function obtenerUltimoIdChat(){
        return $("div[idchat]:last").attr("idchat");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Debido a que no tengo tu código de `load_chat.php` he creado este que es simple y devuelve la primera vez 5 lineas de chat y las sgtes veces solo una linea de chat.

**Codigo back** (ajuste en .php):

```
<?php
    require("conectarbd.php");
    include ("app/data.php");

////**This file is for languages    
if (@$_COOKIE["muser"]!='') {   
    require ("languages/".userdata('language',false).".php");
} else {
    require ("languages/".$Language.".php");
}




$id = $_GET['v']; 
////** This is to know if the room exists   
    $DataPaste = mysql_query("SELECT * from paste WHERE pasteID=$id ");
if (mysql_num_rows($DataPaste) == 0)
{
            echo '<br><br><br><center><img src="'.$sitio_url.'img/500.png"></img><br>
            '.$Languages_136.'!</center>';

}else{ 
    //SO, recibe flag primera_vez que carga pagina
    $flagPrimeraVez = $_GET['flagPrimeraVez'];
    @$idchat = $_GET['idchat'];

    //SO, validando flag
    if($idchat!='' && $idchat>0){//SO, seria despues de la primera vez, entonces se carga solomensajes nuevos
        $data_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * from chat WHERE post=$id AND id>$idchat ");            
    }else{//SO, de lo contrario solo carga todos los mensajes
        $data_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * from chat WHERE post=$id ");
    }

        if (mysql_num_rows($data_chat) == 0)
        {         
            //SO, en primera vez si no hay mensajes se muestra imagen no_messages.png       
            if($flagPrimeraVez=='1'){
                    echo '<br><br><br><center><img src="'.$sitio_url.'img/no_messages.png"></img><br>
                    '.$Languages_12.'!</center>';
            }else{//SO, de lo contrario se envia mensaje en blanco
                echo '';
            }
        }else{  

            while($res=mysql_fetch_array($data_chat)){
                    $ads=$res["ads"];
                    $pads=$res["pads"];
                    $embed=$res["link"];
                    $tipo=$res["tipo"];

/////Mensaje
                        $come[0]='';
                        $come[1]=''.$Ads_Two.'';
// // // // // // // // // // // // // // Content Type------------------------->
// // // // // // chat
                         //SO, agregando idchat
                         $type[0]='<div idchat='.$res["id"].' id="chat" class="message__chat">
                                            <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                        <div id="chat" class="wall_chat_body">
                                            <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam><br>'.parseString(nl2br(bb_parse(Hashtag(''.$res["mensaje"].'')))).'</p>
                                        </div>
                                   </div>'.$come[$ads].'';
// // // // // // imagen        
                        //SO, agregando idchat
                        $type[1]='<div idchat='.$res["id"].' id="chat">
                                <div class="message__img">
                                        <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                    <div class="wall_chat_body_image">
                                        <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="message__chat m--user">
                                        <div class="message__text t--user">
                                            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-media" data-id="'.$res["id"].'" id="getMedia">
                                            <img class="playgif" data-swap="Thumbnails?img='.upload_image($res["id"]).'&data='.$res["post"].'" src="Thumbnails?img='.upload_image($res["id"]).'&thumbs=1&data='.$res["post"].'" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
// // // // // // audio     

                        $type[2]='<div idchat='.$res["id"].' id="chat"><div class="message__img">
                                                <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                            <div class="wall_chat_body_image">
                                                <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam></p>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                <div class="message__chat m--user">
                                    <p class="message__text t--user">
                                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-media" data-id="'.$res["id"].'" id="getMedia">
                                    <img src="img/tool.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
                                    </a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>';    



////** Here are the chat messages   
                echo $type[$tipo];
////** This is the function for external links                  
                echo ''.External_links($res["link"]).''; 

            }
        }
}
```

?>

Ten en cuenta que el chat, tiene una sección de entrada de nuevos mensajes, te recomiendo que ahí también trabajes con ajax, para que con cada mensaje escrito y enviado no recargue la pagina

Comment: guau tu código es muy bueno pero porque repite los mensajes y el php esta bien el problama esta en el ajax

Comment: Gracias. Los mensajes solo son de prueba para diferenciarlos tienen un numero aleatorio con un background aleatorio si te fijas bien tienen dentro la variable $nro y $bg, pudiste probar?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/U0fZz está clonando los mensajes cada segundo

Comment: Aparte de ello,  entonces ya no parpadea?

Comment: no ya no parpadea ahora solo copia los mensajes

Comment: El problema de clonar los mensajes es por el php. Revisa bien esa parte, la idea es que devuelva solo **los mensajes nuevos** si no hay mensajes nuevos entonces debería devolver en blanco.

Comment: En firefox y chrome, presiona F12 y vas a la sección consola o network, aparecerán las peticiones que se envían cada segundo, dale doble click y vas a respuesta o response, revisa ahi que cuando no hay mensaje nuevo llegue en blanco. Estoy seguro que están llegando por eso los duplica, entonces deberás ajustar el .php

Comment: a ver está seguro que es el php ? me puedes dar un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo y Si te Ganastes la reputación

Comment: Si 99%, el codigo dice claramente  **if($.trim(contenido)!='')** a menos que tu pagina este recargandose o algo que haga que se ejecute la función **llenaMensajePrimeraVez**, si te das cuenta esa funcion solo se llama la primera vez.

Comment: Puse uno en la parte php que publique, para un ejemplo adaptado a tu código, necesito publiques tu código para poder guiarme.

Comment: el código ya lo pune y Gracias por la ayuda :D

Comment: Cada mensaje en tu Base de Datos debe tener un identificador único, que posiblemente sea `autoincrement` en la tabla **chat** que es de donde veo que sacas los mensajes, cual es ese campo? lo sabes? porque no veo que lo uses en el código. Dame el nombre del campo y si es autoincrement?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/YQaLl

Comment: ok, ese "id" debemos meterlo al codigo html, para despues en cada llamada por ajax enviarlo y poderlo incluir en la consulta a BD, hare referencia a el como **idchat**. ajustare mi respuesta. Acabo de recordar, en tu codigo php recibes una variable "v" ($id = $_GET['v'];) pero en tu codigo javascript nunca la envias, supongo que tu codigo no es del 100% igual al que esta publicado, igual deberas tener en cuenta que tienes que enviar este nuevo parametro **idchat**.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65088/discussion-between-shareiv-and-juliocpiro).

Answer (score 3):

El parpadeo ocurre porque el contenido del div se reemplaza con cada "load" en otras palabras se renderiza.

Para evitar eso actualiza el contenido del div solo con el nuevo mensaje del chat, utilizando append (jquery)

```
var nuevoMensaje;
//obtener solo los nuevos mensajes, mayores a idUltimoMensaje=111
$.get("obtenerNuevosMensaje.php",{idUltimoMensaje:111},function(data){
    nuevoMensaje = data.mensaje;
}
//agregando solo los nuevos mensajes para no renderizar todo el div
$('#mostrar_mensaje').append(nuevoMensaje);
```

deberas crear el archivo obtenerNuevosMensajes.php que devolvera los ultimos mensajes tomando como referencia el "idUltimoMensaje" la consulta seria algo como:

```
Select * from mensajes where idUltimoMensaje>$idUltimoMensaje
```

Esto es una idea, puede haber muchas otras formas.

Comment: voy a ver si me funciona

Comment: no me funciona ahora no se actualiza pero si envía la información

Comment: puedes publicar el codigo actualizado

Comment: el que me pasastes tu?

Comment: tu codigo finalmente como ha quedado con el cambio?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/u4PYY asi ahora no baja el scroll del DIV

Comment: QUE ESTOY HACIENDO MAL?

Comment: despues del append debe ejecutar nuevamente la funcion del scroll ha que el append ha alterado el height

Comment: me puedes pasar tu código porque yo no encuentro una solución porfavor

Comment: Hola, veo que sigues con el problema, yo no tengo un codigo hecho, solo respondí la consulta. Tratare de ayudarte necesito que publiques tu código html donde esta "#mostrar_mensaje".

Answer (score 3):

Una opción es la que te paso Julio Piro y es la que deberias intentar de implementar, aunque debas modificar tu código.

Otra menos elegante puede ser esta:

a `.load()` le podés pasar un selector más específico para indicar **que porción del html cargar**

Así podés cargar el último mensaje nada más.

Suponiendo que tu chat tiene mensajes todos con class "message" y también desde el php vienen los mensajes igual

```
$('#mostrar_mensaje').append('<div class="wrapper"</div>');
$('#mostrar_mensaje .wrapper:last').load("load_chat.php .message:last", function(){};
```

Agrego el div.wrapper para tener donde cargar el último mensaje

Comment: no es tal facil el archivo php carga los mensajes y las imagenes y con tu codigo tiene unos errores

Comment: Lo edité, perdón. Debería hacer referencia al .wrapper no .message.

Comment: Igual, si lo que querés es cargar el último mensaje nada más, dberías modificar tu php para que te traiga el ultimo mensaje nada más. Ahora si no sabés cuantos mensajes pueden venir, es otra cosa. Te recomiendo o usar un fadein o un gif para mostrar que se está cargando

Comment: Hola, veo que sigues con el problema, yo no tengo un código hecho, solo respondí la consulta. Tratare de ayudarte necesito que publiques tu código html donde esta "#mostrar_mensaje" y css si lo usas.

Comment: @juliocpiro ya lo puse

Comment: probe tu codigo y no se nota el parpadeo, como es un chat supongo tienes algun input donde el usuario escribe los nuevos mensajes, este funciona con ajax o lo envias con un form y un submit?

Comment: otro problema podria ser la relacion de ese div respecto al restonde componentes de tu pagina, podrias poner una captura de pantalla de tu pagina para ver donde se ubica el chat respecto al resto. Si el problema sigue hare uno desde cero usando append y lo publico

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/ encontré esto pero no se como meter todo este codigo en mi codigo ayudame y te doy la reputasion

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usando directamente innerHTML tiene un mejor performance que hacerlo mediante JQuery

```
$.get("load_chat.php", function(data){  
    document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje").innerHTML=data;
});
```

Comment: mira lo que quiero es que ya no parpadee cada segundo